# Three.js SimplifyModifier modify all buffer geometry attributes?

Tags: three.js, model, attributes, simplify, buffer-geometry

In three.js, I want to use the `SimplifyModifier` to simplify a model to several different degrees. The problem is that the geometry for the model contains attributes for `normals, skinIndex, skinWeight, and position`. The modifier removes all attributes other than position, and in the end, I am left with a black, static geometry. Is there any way I can programmatically create low polygon versions of my buffer geometry which also have these attributes modified as well?

Comment: There is no easy to do that since the simplification process easily messes up your animations. So it's better to create the simplified version of your skinned meshes in a DCC tool like Blender.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I am actually controlling the animations programmatically, but I understand how it messes up the skeleton rigging which controls both that and the animation. I was trying to figure this out because I could either make low poly versions of each clothing piece on my player which would be 12 models or figure out a way to reduce this one geometry which would only be 4 models needed.